# Help with a lemma of the nth root (without the binomial formula)

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, alternative-proof

I have no idea of how to solve it. I would appreciate if someone gives me a hint, please.

**Definitions** Let $\,x^{1/n}:= sup\{\, y \in \mathbb{R}: y\ge0 \text{ and } y^n\le x\, \}$

**Lemma**: Let $x,y>0$ be positive reals, and let $n\ge 0$ be a positive integer.

(a) If $y = x^{1/n}$ then $y^n = x$

(b) Conversely, if $y^n = x$, then $y = x^{1/n}$

The big problems is I cannot use the binomial formula to prove it. I tried to used an argument by contradiction assume $y^n < x$ and so $y^n > x$ to get contradiction. But without the binomial formula I'm not sure of what use as estimator. The hint in the book is use denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and the basic properties of order in $\mathbb{R}$.

I thought to use something like this: Suppose that $y^n < x$ then there is a rational number such that $y^n < q < x$ and after this create a set $E_q$ which is bounded by $q$ find its supremum and try to get a contradiction and a similar argument to $x<y^n$. But that's not work very well. Could someone give me a hint, please?

I think I have the exercise (b)

Proof of (b): Suppose $y^n = x$ and $y > 0$. We set $E:=\{\, z \in \mathbb{R}: z\ge0 \text{ and } z^n\le x\, \}$. It follows that $E \not= \emptyset$ since $y\in E$. Now we need to show that is bounded above but that follows because $E$ is bounded by $\text{max} \{1,x\}$.

To prove the claim is sufficient to show that $y$ is the least upper bound of $E$.

First we have to show that $y$ is an upper bound for $E$. We may argue by contradiction, suppose that there is a $z\in E$ such that $z>y$ so $z^n>y^n=x$, i.e., $z\notin E$ a contradiction. Then for all $z\in E$ we must have $z\le y$.

Now to conclude the proof we need to show that $y$ is the least upper bound of $E$. Let $s$ be an upper bound for $E$ and suppose $s<y$. Then by the denseness of the rational numbers we have $s<q<y$.Then $q^n<y^n=x$ and $q>0$ so $\,q\in E$ contradicting that $s$ is an upper bound. Thus, the upper bound $s$ is greater than equal to $y$, thus $y$ is the least upper bound of $E$ and by definition $y= x^{1/n}$ as desired.

With the part (a) I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Don't you mean $y\in \color{red}{\Bbb Q}$?

Comment: No, $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So $1^1=\sup\left(\{y\in \Bbb R\colon y\ge 0 \land y^1\leq x\}\right)$?

Comment: I check the book and says:"Let $x > 0\,$ be a positive real, and let $n\ge 1\,$ be a positive integer. We define $x^{ 1/n}$, also known as the nth root of x, by the formula: $\,x^{1/n}:= sup\{\, y \in \mathbb{R}: y\ge0 \text{ and } y^n\le x\, \}$"

Comment: Ok, ok. I just find it odd.

Comment: What can you use, if you mustn't use the binomial theorem? If you can argue that $p_n \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}; p_n(\xi) = \xi^n$ is continuous and strictly increasing, it's pretty straightforward. But I guess that's strictly off limits ;)

Comment: Yes, it's in the next chapter when the author define limits and the binomial formula is define two chapter on. At this moment the book construct the real as formal limits of Cauchy sequences and I proved all the order properties that follows immediately for the rational numbers since both obey the same laws of algebra and the least upper bound property; that's all. It is my second day in this problem and I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: I have not a good idea of how to do it. Maybe the best way is to prove the binomial formula but I don't think is what the author was thinking when wrote the exercise. Because the formula is not even mentioned at this point in the book, I know is very easy the proof using induction but I'm not completely happy with this approach... Am I totally off track? Is there another way without using the binomial theorem to prove it?

Comment: Nobody knows? Please any hint would be so helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem (a) you can use this inequality, holding for $z>0$, $0<t\le 1$ and $n$ integer:

$$
(z+t)^n \le z^n + t((z+1)^n - z^n)
$$

If $z^n<x$, then you can find $t$ such that $(z+t)^n<x$: just take $t$ such that
$$
0<t<\min\left\{\frac{x-z^n}{(z+1)^n-z^n},1\right\}
$$
which surely exists. Therefore such a $z$ can't be the supremum of the set $\{y\ge0:y^n\le x\}$ and for the supremum $\xi$ of this set it must be $\xi^n=x$.

---

How do you find that inequality? It doesn't matter, because you can prove it by induction on $n$. It clearly holds for $n=0$. Suppose it holds for $n$; then
\begin{align}
(z+t)^{n+1}
&=(z+t)^n(z+t)\\
&\le(z^n+t(z+1)^n-tz^n)(z+t)\\
&=z^{n+1}+tz(z+1)^n-tz^{n+1}+tz^n+t^2(z+1)^n-t^2z^n\\
&< z^{n+1}+tz(z+1)^n+t(z+1)^n-tz^{n+1}-t^2z^n\\
&=z^{n+1}+t(z+1)^{n+1}-tz^{n+1}-t^2z^n\\
&\le z^{n+1}+t(z+1)^{n+1}-tz^{n+1}
\end{align}

The hypothesis $0<t\le 1$ is used to get the second $\le$, since $t^2\le t$.

Tell your teacher an elf suggested it. `;-)` Of course one can also prove it with the binomial theorem:
\begin{align}
(z+t)^n
&=z^n+\binom{n}{1}z^{n-1}t+\binom{n}{2}z^{n-2}t^2+\dots+\binom{n}{n-1}zt^{n-1}+t^n\\
&\le z^n+\binom{n}{1}z^{n-1}t+\binom{n}{2}z^{n-2}t+\dots+\binom{n}{n-1}zt+t\\
&=z^n+t((z+1)^n-z^n)
\end{align}
(which is how I first got it). The idea came from the same problem but with $n=2$, which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide a complete proof which was inspired by ergreg.
**Proof** Let $E := sup\{t \in \mathbb{R}:t \ge 0 \text{ and }t^{n}\leq x \}$, then by definition $y = sup(E)$. In order to prove $y^{n}=x$, we show that both $y^{n} <x$ and $y^{n} >x$ lead to contradictions.First suppose that  $y^{n}<x$. Let $0< \epsilon <1$ be a small real number, here we want to find an $\epsilon$ such that $(y+\epsilon)^n<x$. Since $0<\epsilon<1$, we have
$$
(y+\epsilon)^{n}-(y)^{n} \leq \epsilon((y+1)^{n}-(y)^{n})
$$
Transform it, we have
$$
(y+\epsilon)^{n} \leq (y)^{n}+\epsilon((y+1)^{n}-(y)^{n})
$$
Let the right side$$
(y)^{n}+\epsilon((y+1)^{n}-(y)^{n})\le x$$then we have $$\epsilon\le \frac {x-(y)^n}{(y+1)^{n}-(y)^{n})}$$So when 
$$
0<\epsilon<\min\left\{\frac{x-y^n}{(y+1)^n-y^n},1\right\}
$$
we have $(y+\epsilon)^n<x$, which implies that $y+\epsilon\in E$.But it contradicts that fact that $y$ is an upper bound of $E$ as $y+\epsilon >y$.

     Second suppose that  $y^{n}>x$. Let $0< \epsilon <1$ be a small real number, here we want to find an $\epsilon$ such that $(y-\epsilon)^n>x$. Since $0<\epsilon<1$, we have
$$
(y)^{n}-(y-\epsilon)^{n} \leq \epsilon((y)^{n}-(y-1)^{n})
$$
Transform it, we have
$$
(y-\epsilon)^{n} \ge (y)^{n}-\epsilon((y)^{n}-(y-1)^{n})
$$
Let the right side
$$
(y)^{n}-\epsilon((y)^{n}-(y-1)^{n})\ge x$$
then we have 
$$
\epsilon\leq \frac {(y)^n-x}{(y)^{n}-(y-1)^{n})}$$
So when 
$$
0<\epsilon<\min\left\{\frac{y^n-x}{(y)^n-(y-1)^n},1\right\}
$$
we have $(y-\epsilon)^n>x$.But this implies that $e \le y-\epsilon$ for all $e \in E$. (If $e>y-\epsilon$, then $e^n>(y-\epsilon)^n>x$, a contradiction.) Thus $y-\epsilon$ is an upper bound for, which contradicts the fact that $y$ is the least upper bound for $E$ as $y-\epsilon<y$.From these two contradictions we see that $y^n=x$, as desired.