# Every positive real number has a unique positive $k$-th root

Tags: real-analysis, roots, real-numbers

Here is my proof so far:
Want to show there is a unique positive number $b$ such that $b^k = a$. Define the set $A = \{x>0: x^k>a\}$ of numbers too big to be $k$-th root.
$A$ is nonempty as $x = (1+a)$ is in $A$ as is min $(1+a)$ which $>a$
By definition of set $A$ is bounded below by $0$ so greatest lower bound characterisation of completeness implies $b= \inf A$ must exist. For each natural number $n$, there exists an belonging to A such that $b \le a < b+1/n$.
Past here I need help with writing out the working.
I then have to show $(an)^k$ tends to $b^k$ to conclude $b^k\geq  a$ and I am particularly unsure of this step.
I then have to show $b^k\geq  a$ by contradiction. I assume $b^k > a$then $0$ $<a/b^k< 1$ so may choose $d <b/k(1-a/b^k)$
I then have to achieve a contradiction by choosing $b-d$ belonging to $A$. This will show $b^k = a $and then I have to prove there are no other positive kth roots

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I did something similar some months ago, outlined here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642518/prove-existence-of-nth-roots-for-non-negative-real-numbers/3647865#3647865

Answer (score 0):

Imagine there exists $b>0$ and $b'>0$ with $b' \neq b$ but with $b^k=a$ and $b'^k=a$, then:

$$
b' \neq b
$$

Taking both sides to the power of $k$:
$$
b'^k \neq b^k
$$

And from the hypothesis $b^k=a$ and $b'^k=a$ we get:
$$
a \neq a
$$

Which is a contradiction. Hence, if the positive root $b$ exists, it is unique.

To prove it exists, we can create a sequence that converges to the root. Let $t_0=0$ and $w_0 = a$, then do the following:

$$u_n = (t_{n-1} + w_{n-1})/2 $$

If $u_n^k >a$, then  $w_n = u_n$ and $t_n = t_{n-1}$ otherwise $t_n = u_n$ and $w_n = w_{n-1}$. This is the bisection method. The sequence $t_n$ is non-decreasing and limited, and $w_n$ is non-increasing limited, hence they both converge to the same value as $u_n$. Say $u_n \to u$, then $u^k = a$. Hence the value exists and is positive.